# Is using SCOPE_IDENTITY() affecting performance for my batch insert?

Tags: sql, performance

I am processing data ('events') and inserting the results into tables for reporting purposes.
Data is inserted in bulk so I'm using stored procedures.

The various event types have common and specific fields so the INSERT statement looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Event](EventID, ...) VALUES(@EventID, ...)
INSERT INTO [FileEvent](EventID, ...) VALUES(@EventID, ...)
```

with a 1:1 relationship between Event and FileEvent.

EventID used to be supplied by the raw data. Recently, I've had to modify the EventID column to be an IDENTITY column (duplicate EventIDs in the raw data so couldn't use that as the input anymore). The INSERT statement now looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Event](...) VALUES(...)
declare @EventID int
SET @EventID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO [FileEvent](EventID, ...) VALUES(@EventID, ...)
```

This works fine, but I've can see a noticeable decrease in performance as the data is inserted in the batch process.  For example, the INSERT where I supplied the IDs completes in 15min, where the INSERT where IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY() is used completes in 18min.

Granted the SQL server has more work to do (composing the new ID etc), but am I obtaining the ID in an inefficient manner?  Is there a more efficient way to perform the insert into both tables?

Comment: If you can change your queries to insert data in a bulk, insert into has an OUTPUT clause that can add all inserted IDs into a (temp)table so you can insert the IDs in the second table in a batch as well. Not sure if that will help...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the output clause of the insert statement to save the identity value to a variable or temp table.

That way you can also insert bigger batches in fewer statements. You can send the data in using table valued parameters. The speedup that you can see is very significant, like an order of magnitude. Definitely worth a look for bulk operations.